# Approximation for nth prime in arithmetic progressions

Tags: number-theory

Is there a good approximation for the nth prime in arithmetic progressions, namely the $4n+1$ progression. I have found the one that stems directly from the prime number theorem on arithmetic progressions:
$$\frac{\pi(x;a,q) \log(x) \phi(q)}{x} = 1$$
$$\log(\pi(x; a,q))+ \log(\log(x))+ \log(\phi(q)) - \log(x) = 0$$
$$\frac{\log(\pi(x; a,q))}{\log(x)}+ \frac{\log(\log(x))}{\log(x)}+ \frac{\log(\phi(q))}{\log(x)} - 1 = 0$$
$$\frac{\log(\pi(x; a,q))}{\log(x)} + 0 + 0 = 1$$
Multiply by the original.
$$\frac{\pi(x;a,q) \log(x) \phi(q)\log(\pi(x; a,q))}{x\log(x)} = 1$$
$$\frac{\pi(x;a,q) \phi(q)\log(\pi(x; a,q))}{x} = 1$$
Let $x=p_n$, where $p_n$ is the nth prime in $\pi(x;a,q)$.
$$\frac{\phi(q) x \log(x)}{p_n} = 1$$
That is one approximation. But when I look at the regular prime number thoerem, there is a more accurate result in addition to this method. I was wondering if there a more accurate one for this progression too.

Comment: What do you mean by a more accurate result?

Comment: Replace $x/\log x$ by $Li(x)$ or $\sum_{n \le x} 1/\ln n$, under the PNT they are $O(x/\log^k x)$ approximations for every $k$, under the GRH they are $O(x^{1/2} \log x)$ . To improve the error term's O-constant you need things like the Riemann R-function (leading to the prime number races) and to improve more than that you need sums over the non-trivial zeros of Dirichlet L-functions

Comment: Thank you @reuns